# Patent-free Interest Point Detector?

Tags: local-features

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free alternatives to SIFT/SURF for commercial use](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/free-alternatives-to-sift-surf-for-commercial-use)

There are same very good algorithms for interest point detection/description, like:

- SIFT (Scale-Invariant Feature Transform)
- SURF (Speeded-Up Robust Features)
- MOPs (Multi-Scale Oriented Patches)

Regrettably, at least the first two are patented and cannot be used commercially without paying huge fees to the authors. I am currently negotiating about the third one, which is patented as well.

In a search for patent-free algorithm, I found there is a multitude of patents like [this one](http://www.faqs.org/patents/app/20080267506#b). Huh?! Is there merely anything usable then?

Maybe at least Harris-Laplace or some basic detector can be used. But how to be sure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(IANAL...)

If you only want detectors:

- Harris is probably OK.
- According to http://users.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/~steve/susan/, SUSAN is out of patent now.
- I've not seen any claims that [FAST](http://www.edwardrosten.com/work/fast.html) is patented.

Descriptors are harder...

[Histograms of Oriented Gradients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) might be worth considering - again I've not seen any claims of patent on the original form.

Comment: Thanks. I will finally go for the multi-scale Harris-Laplace detector. The descriptor will consists simply of normalized gradients if it would be sufficient. If not, that affine invariant version is also proposed my Mikolajczyk & Schmidt, which I believe is also patent-free.